# Change display values for JavaFX Axis

Tags: java, javafx, axis

NumberAxis and CategoryAxis are used for plotting my AreaChart.
[image]

I would like to know how can I change display values for both axis since I need to:

- display humanReadableByteCount (KB, MB, GB) instead of bytes representation for the Y axis
- display the hour:minute:second only for thee X axis

I was unable to find any information on how to modify the display values in the doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html

Comment: Have you tried using a [tickLabelFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/ValueAxis.html#tickLabelFormatterProperty) for the number axis?

Comment: IIUC, categories must be unique. What happens if you reformat them?

Comment: For categories, I think you could subclass CategoryAxis and override [getTickMarkLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/CategoryAxis.html#getTickMarkLabel-java.lang.String-).

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: I am not sure how to transform bytes in KB, MB, GB using `setTickLabelFormatter`.  This method requires `StringConverter<T>` and I am not sure how can I use my representation `static String humanReadableByteCountSI(Integer bytesString)` for this new format.

Comment: @feedthemachine: Wouldn't you invoke the method in your implementation of `toString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by implementing `setTickLabelFormatter` which overrides toString:

```
    ratesAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Number t) {
            return String.valueOf(ReadFile.humanReadableByteCountSI(t));
        }

        @Override
        public Number fromString(String string) {
            return 1;
        }
    });
```

From another class:

```
static String humanReadableByteCountSI(Number bytesString) {
    int bytes = (int) bytesString.intValue();
    if (-1000 < bytes && bytes < 1000) {
        return bytes + " B";
    }
    CharacterIterator ci = new StringCharacterIterator("kMGTPE");
    while (bytes <= -999_950 || bytes >= 999_950) {
        bytes /= 1000;
        ci.next();
    }
    return String.format("%.1f %cB", bytes / 1000.0, ci.current());
}
```

Result:
[image]